# C struct to Java JNA Structure (pointer to struct)

Tags: java, c, struct, structure, jna

I have problem with JNA Structure based on C/C++ struct. Fields nScreenIndex, uVendorID, uProductID, uVersionNumber looks OK, but after them I see odd bytes. My main and only goal is to "extract" pMonitor fields.
Are **pMonitor** declaration and **MONITOR** implementation correct?

C/C++ origin:

```
SCREEN* EloGetScreenByIndex (int nScreenIndex);

typedef struct SCREEN_TAG
{
    int               nScreenIndex;
    USHORT            uVendorID;     
    USHORT            uProductID;    
    USHORT            uVersionNumber;
    wchar_t           szDevicePath [MAX_PATH];
    HANDLE            hCalTouchThread;
    MONITOR*          pMonitor;
    LPVOID            pCWndBeamHandler;
    BOOL              bIrBeams;
} SCREEN;

typedef struct MONITORS_TAG
{
    int     elo_mon_num;
    int     x;
    int     y;
    int     width;
    int     height;
    DWORD   orientation;
    bool    is_primary;
} MONITOR;
```

and Java/JNA code:

```
SCREEN EloGetScreenByIndex(int nScreenIndex);

public class SCREEN extends Structure {
    public int nScreenIndex;
    public short uVendorID;
    public short uProductID;
    public short uVersionNumber;
    public char[] szDevicePath = new char[WinDef.MAX_PATH];
    public WinNT.HANDLE hCalTouchThread;
    public MONITOR pMonitor;
    public PointerByReference pCWndBeamHandler;
    public boolean bIrBeams;
    ...
}

public class MONITOR extends Structure {
    public int elo_mon_num;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int orientation;
    public byte is_primary;

    public MONITOR() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("elo_mon_num", "x", "y", "width", "height", "orientation", "is_primary");
    }

    public MONITOR(Pointer peer) {
        super(peer);
    }

    public static class ByReference extends MONITOR implements Structure.ByReference {
    };

    public static class ByValue extends MONITOR implements Structure.ByValue {
    };
}
```

Comment: `pCWndBeamHandler` should be `Pointer`, not `PointerByReference`.  You should also add a `Pointer`-based constructor for each `Structure` which calls `Structure.read()` after `super()` (not critical, but avoids unnecessary extra memory allocations).

Answer (score 2):

You're so very close to right.

in the SCREEN class in java, you need to define `pMonitor` as:

```
    public MONITOR.ByReference pMonitor;
```

This is [per the FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure).

> When should I use Structure.ByReference? Structure.ByValue? Structure[]?

```
typedef struct _outerstruct2 {
  simplestruct *byref; // use Structure.ByReference
} outerstruct2;
```

As an addendum:

> When I stubbed this up using a mingw compiled `dll`, I had to inherit from `StdCallLibrary` and not `Library` - this may not be the case for you, I'm just mentioning this as it affected my testing.

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfectly. There were two issues: lack of ".ByReference" and bad (default) data alignment in structures. 
I had to change MONITOR into MONITOR.ByReference and super() into super(ALIGN_NONE). 
ALIGN_NONE set no alignment on structures, place all fields on nearest 1-byte boundary.

Comment: There is nothing in the C++ code that indicates that it's using 8bit packing; but glad that it's working for you. Altered packing rules like this are quite uncommon - there's nothing in the mentioned C++ interface that indicates that this is the case.

Comment: I don't have C/C++ source code - I have only *.dll and *.h files, but it looks like Elo Touch Solutions developers use 1-byte aligned for their touchscreen crappy API.

Comment: BTW: Is there any way to set global memory byte alignment for all data structures in JNA library (*.dll Java wrapper)?
Currently I'm doing this in very clumsy way - I'm setting data alignment (super(ALIGN_NONE)) in each and every structure (a lot of structures in separate files).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809144/how-to-set-global-memory-byte-alignment-for-all-structures-in-jna-library