# How to set global memory byte alignment for all structures in JNA library?

Tags: java, structure, global, jna, memory-alignment

Is there any way to set global memory byte alignment for all data structures in JNA library (*.dll Java wrapper)?

Sometimes I have to determine correct alignment by trial and error during implementation and currently I'm doing this in very clumsy way - I'm setting data alignment (super(ALIGN_NONE)) in each and every structure (a lot of structures in separate files).

edit:
The best way to solve my problem was to extend Structure:

```
public abstract class StructureAligned extends Structure {
    public static final int STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT = ALIGN_NONE;

    protected StructureAligned() {
        super(STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT);
    }

    protected StructureAligned(Pointer p) {
        super(p, STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}
```

..but this led to next question: Which (Pointer) constructor is better and why:

```
super(p, STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT);
```

or

```
super(STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT);
read();
```

or

```
super(STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT);
useMemory(p);
read();
```

?

Comment: All data structures on the heap are 8 byte aligned.  Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean n-byte alignment of fields in structures based on com.sun.jna.Structure. This question is connected to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747228/c-c-struct-to-java-jna-structure-pointer-to-struct

Answer (score 2):

Make your own `Structure` subclass and call the appropriate constructor with the desired alignment type, or call `setAlignType()` in the constructor.

If JNA is not correctly calculating the appropriate default alignment for the most commonly used compiler on the platform, then you should file a bug against JNA.

If, however, you have a library that simply uses a bunch of arbitrary alignments for its own internal reasons, then turning off alignment for all your `Structure` classes via a common base class is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To make this apply globally, update the default value in the Native library options map when your library is instantiated

```
public class MyLibrary implements Library {
    static {
        Native.register(MyLibrary.class, NativeLibrary.getInstance("somenativelib"));
        Native.getLibraryOptions(MyLibrary.class).put(Library.OPTION_STRUCTURE_ALIGNMENT, Structure.ALIGN_NONE);
    }
}
```